# How to create a file with random char in C?

Tags: c, string, char, metaprogramming

I have no problem in generate random numbers with rand()
I have to create an output file with a string of char e.g. "AQSDJEIOFHDUK" 
When the result of rand ()%26 +1 is 1 I've to print in the file "A" when the result is "2" B and so on. I already know a priori how many char will be in the string let's say 50. 
I've to do that in C language.
Which function I should use? 
Strcat?

Comment: How about using `fputc`...

Comment: Please post some code examples to show us what you tried and where you're stuck, otherwise it's very hard to know how to help. ... Also, without showing us an attempt, it mostly feels as if you're asking us to do your homework for you, and I'm sure this isn't what you meant.

Comment: If you're learning why not do it yourself by adding 64 to the random number and outputting that. In ASCII "A" is 65.

Comment: `int n = 50; while(n--){ fputc(rand() % 26 + 'A', fp); }`

Comment: No, we do not add `1` to `64` but add `0` to `'A'`, just like BLUEPIXY did above.

Answer (score 3):

Simple set an array with random letters selected via `rand()`

```
#define RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH 50

char buf[RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
for (size_t i = 0; i < RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH; i++) {
  buf[i] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[rand() %26];
}
buf[RANDOM_STRING_LENGTH] = '\0';

puts(buf);
```

Comment: Plus, this method allowss easily to skip some characters (for example I and O as they look like numbers)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASCII table of characters to generate valid characters. The base for the uppercase alphabet is at 65, so when you generate

```
int rnd = rand() % 26;
```

you can say something like

```
char new_char = 65 + rnd;
```

or as others have stated, it is easier to read

```
char new_char = 'A' + rnd;
```

which should give you one character in the ascii table of characters based off of the result of `rand() % 26`. Remember, in C an unsigned char is really just a data type that can range from the number 0, to the number 255.
(as stated below, a signed char can range from -126 to 127)

Things like `'a'` and `'b'` are translated into their ascii equivalent. (i.e. the corresponding number between 0 and 255 that they represent.)

(unless you are using UNICODE of course.)

I hope this helped.

Comment: `char new_char = 'A' + rnd` Easier to read :)

Comment: you mean `char new_char = ('A' - 1) + rnd;` (since 65 + 1 would give OP "B", and OP wants to get "A" when rnd is equal to 1) :)

Comment: `rnd` can be 0, you are starting with 64+0 = @

Comment: True, but OP said that when `rnd` is `1`, he wants to generate 'A' :(

Comment: @mikebayko, e.g. `rand() %26` can only return `0-25` not `1-26`.

Comment: @above point made. I will change my code.

Comment: You are right, but you should point that out just in case OP is wrong about what he wants.

Comment: "C a char is really jsut a data type that can range from the number 0, to the number 255." is not specified by C and is not needed in this answer.  It could be -128 to 127, 0 to 65535, etc.

Comment: @chux good point, although I am pretty sure that chars are only 1 byte in size in C? (0 to 255 would be unsigned char)

Comment: Yes, in C a `char` is 1 byte, _signed_ or _unsigned_. The trick is that a byte may be 8,9, 16, etc. bits.  8 bits is the most common.

Comment: But what about words, dwords, and qwords?

Comment: @mikebayko "words, dwords, and qwords" are not defined by C.  They mean whatever a given implementation wants them to mean.